# C++ Pointer to Non-static Member Function Using Templates

Tags: c++, function-pointers, virtual-functions, pointer-to-member

I'm having trouble getting member function pointers to work (I don't know whether what I'm trying to do is possible).  I want to set a member variable (which is a pointer to a non-static function in another class) and then call that function.  I then want to be able to set it to another member function in a different derived class and call that.  The 2 derived classes are created by templates, as per below.  Can I achieve this and if so, what am I doing wrong?

```
// Forward declare these, their implementation is irrelevant to the question 
class A;
class B;

// declare a base class that contains a function log() that we want to call
class BaseClass {
   public:
      BaseClass() {}
      virtual ~BaseClass() {}

      virtual void log() {}  // want to call this via function pointers
};

//Using a template means we don't have to specify the type in the vector  
template<class T>
class TemplateVectorOfBaseClass : public BaseClass {
   protected:
      std::vector<T> peripherals;      
}

//  this specific implementation does stuff using Class A
template <int randomTemplateParameter>
class DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithAs : public BaseClass
    public:
       DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithAs() : TemplateVectorOfBaseClass<A>() {}
       void log() {do_something_here_involving_As();}
       int i[randomTemplateParameter];
};

//  this specific implementation does stuff using Class B
template <int randomTemplateParameter>
class DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithBs : public BaseClass
    public:
       DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithBs() : TemplateVectorOfBaseClass<B>() {}
       void log() {do_something_here_involving_Bs();}
       float f[randomTemplateParameter];  
};

// Class that contains both templates as member variables    
class ContainerClass {
   public:
      ContainerClass();

      DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithAs dtca<5>;
      DerivedTemplateClassThatDoesStuffWithBs dtcb<10>;

      void (BaseClass::*log)();  // pointer to member function log()
    }

// usage
ContainerClass cc;

cc.container.log = &dtca.log;
cc.*log(); // should call vectorContainingAs.log()

cc.container.log = &dtcb.log;
cc.*log(); // should call vectorContainingBs.log()
```

Comment: `class ContainerClass { public: ContainerClass container;`. How could this ever compile?

Comment: Your example is still a little unclear.  cc.*log() doesn't make sense.  You intend to run the function pointed at by "cc.log" against the "cc" object?  Or did you intend it to run against the dtca object?

Comment: You can't use pointers to non-static functions.

Comment: @dari Of course you can. Your code contains lots of errors irrelevant to the specified problem, you should correct them before pasting it.

Comment: @Holt oh yeah, thx. Thinking before posting helps.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have a compiler to hand at the time I typed.  Edited to correct constructor typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really rely on your code because it's full of mistakes, so here it's how it should work with a simplified version:

```
class A { } ;
class B { } ;    

class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void log () {
        std::cout << "Log BaseClass." << std::endl ;
    }
};

template <class T>
class TVector : public BaseClass { } ;

template <int N>
class DTCA : public TVector <A> { 
public:
    virtual void log () { 
        std::cout << "Log DTCA." << std::endl ;
    }
} ;

template <int N>
class DTCB : public TVector <B> { 
public:
    virtual void log () {
        std::cout << "Log DTCB." << std::endl ;
    }
} ;

class Container {
public:
    DTCA <5> dtca ;
    DTDB <10> dtcb ;
    void (BaseClass::*log) () ;
} ;
```

I assume the mistakes in the previous part was due to bad copy/paste. The part where you were mainly wrong was the way of assigning the method to the pointer, and the way to call the method on an object:

```
int main () {
    Container cc ;
    cc.log = &BaseClass::log ; // Store the log member function into cc.log

    (cc.dtca.*cc.log) () ; // Call it on dtca
    (cc.dtcb.*cc.log) () ; // Call it on dtcb

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

> Log DTCA.
>
> Log DTCB.

You can not take the address of a method from an instance, you will get something like:

> ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.

So you take the address to the method, since the type of your variable is `(BaseClass::*)()` you need to take it directly from the `BaseClass`. Then, you need to call it using an instance of `BaseClass` or a derived class.